# Why when i click the check box the notification appears after 10 seconds?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-notifications, android-checkbox

Hi my code to display a notification about the battery level has a little problem. I've insert the code of the preferences insid the `onReceive` like:

```
private BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        // prefer
        setPref.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){    
            @Override    
            public void onClick(View arg0) {     
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,settings.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }});         
        checkPref();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void checkPref() {
        SharedPreferences myPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
        boolean pref_opt1 = myPref.getBoolean("pref_opt1", false); 
        int level= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,-1);

        if (pref_opt1) {
            NotificationManager notifi = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setContentTitle("Battery Informations")
                    .setContentText("Batteria al"+" "+level+"%")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_small_not)
                    .setTicker(level+"%")
                    .build();

            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); 
            PendingIntent penInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0 , i , 0);
            notifi.notify(215,notification);
        } else {
            NotificationManager notifi = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notifi.cancel(215);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        checkPref();
    }
}
```

Everything goes well but when i check the box the notification appear after about 10 seconds. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you receive a broadcast, you're checking to see if the checkbox is checked (in checkPref()), what's happening is you're checking the box, then you receive the broadcast, and you post the notification. What would you like it to do?

Comment: I should add, it's not a good practice to have all of those annotations in your code. Do you have a specific reason for them, or are you just using code you got from somewhere and doing what eclipse wants you to do to make the little yellow squiggles go away?

Comment: Well, What i want it'ss simply display the battery level notification if the check box in the preferences Is checked.Is this the wrong way?

Comment: you want it to add the battery level to the notification bar as a result of you checking the box (right away, not some time later), right?

Comment: Yeah, when i check the check box the notification of battery level in notifications bar will display. When unchecked obviously disappear. But must be instantaneous.